# Continuity vs differentiability versus directional derivatives

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I'm having trouble with understanding the different concepts of continuity, differentiability and the existence of directional derivatives.
I am given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, f(0)=0$ and $x=(x_1,x_2)$, such that $f(x)=\frac{x_1^3}{||x||}$ when $x$ is nonzero.

I'm asked to prove that this function is continuous at the origin, but I'm also asked to prove that all directional derivatives exist in the origin, and to prove that it is not differentiable. To me this is very confusing. How can this function be continuous and at the same time not differentiable? Doesn't the one imply the other? And how are directional derivatives related to this?

Comment: How can this function be continuous and at the same time not differentiable? Surely you have seen examples in one variable.

Comment: That should be f(0,0) = 0. Also, f appears to be differentiable everywhere to me.

Answer (score 0):

A differentiable function must be continuous, but not vice versa. A good explanation of this can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_and_continuity).